# GraphQL check for unique record on mutation

Tags: mongodb, reactjs, mongoose, graphql, relay

On a GraphQL mutation, how can I check in the resolve function if the record I´m trying to create is unique ?

Consider the code:

```
const createUser = {
    type: UserType,
    description: 'Creates an user',
    args: {
        data: {
            name: 'user',
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(UserInputType)
        }
    },
    resolve(root, args) {

        let data = args.data;

       UserModel.findByName(data.name);
             ??? How can I return an error here if there is a user with 
             ??? the given name already stored in database ?

        const model = new UserModel(data);
        model.save();
    }
}
```

Should I keep that logic on the GraphQL Server or should I leave it to the database layer. If I leave it to the database layer, how can I return the database error to my client, so that he knows he´s trying to create an invalid user ?

I´m the following stack: MongoDB, express, Mongoose, graphql-js on server, ReactJS and Relay on client.